# Can't install a dependency?

Tags: installation, apt, uninstall, ppa

I've been trying to install 'boot-repair' but it keeps saying:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>       Depends: boot-sav (>= 3.196) but 3.196~ppa3~quantal is to be installed
>
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

When I try installing 'boot-sav', everything seems okay, but when I try it again, it just shows the same message over and over again. How can I fix such a problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I guess [it's a bug... .](https://bugs.launchpad.net/boot-repair/+bug/1090841)

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install -f`

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting this error booting off the 12.10 live CD, and no amount of apt repair (including apt-get install -f) fixes it.

I get the same problem (substituting "precise" for "quantal" in the installed version of boot-sav) booting from the 12.04 LTS live CD.

But what should work, and I'm about to do, is to download the ubuntu-secure-remix CD and use that, as it has it already successfully installed.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuSecureRemix

There's an alternative out there that's slightly smaller (I've misplaced the link), but it doesn't support UEFI, while the 64-bit version of ubuntu-secure-remix does, and both versions are relatively up-to-date, being based on 12.10.

[Edit: And indeed, as expected, the CD did allow me to repair my boot setup.]

Answer (score 0):

Bob Kerns answer is good. Another much cheaper(700% smaller) and effective alternative, the one I eventually used was to install and use [grub-customizer](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/grub-customizer-graphical-interface-to-configure-the-grub2burg-settings.html)...

The GUI is great and it seems to do the job better than any other boot fix utility.